# Meaning of the simplest potential of quintessence models. Fields in denominator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, field-theory, cosmological-inflation, cosmological-constant

I am reading Sec. 1.12 of the Cosmology book by Weinberg.

In this section he explains the very simple model of quintessence which attempts to provide a dynamical explanation of the smallness of the cosmological constant today.

He considers an example of a time-dependent but space-independent scalar field in a space with Robertson-Walker metric

$$
\mathcal{L} = \int d^4 x \sqrt{-det(g)} \left[\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi + V(\phi)\right], \tag{1}
$$

where, in the simplest case, the following potential seems to make the job (naively)

$$
V(\phi) = \frac{M^{\alpha+4}}{\phi^\alpha} \tag{2}
$$

for some positive constant $\alpha>0$ and mass scale $M$.

I am used to consider field theories where the potentials are analytic functions of the fields, especially in the point $\phi=0$, e.g. $\phi^4$-theory and standard effective field theories. In particular, all the effective field theories used by Beyond Standard Model phenomenologists involve positive power of fields and derivatives, e.g.

$$
V(\phi) = \sum_{n,k}\partial^n \phi^k
$$

Up to now I thought that fields in denominators were allowed as long as we expand around some constant VEV $v$, for example $\phi \rightarrow v + \delta\phi$, in such a way that any potential of the form $V(\phi) = \phi^{-\alpha}$ is an expansion of analytic interaction terms involving the perturbation $\delta \phi$. Once we do this expansion, we quantize the theory around the minimum $\phi=v$.

Here instead the minimum of the potential is at $\phi=+\infty$ and I have never seen quantization around $\phi=+\infty$.

I have two very related questions.

**Question**

- What is the physical meaning of the potential (2) which blows up for very small values of the field $\phi$?
- Can we interpret this as a theory of particles? If yes, how do you quantize this theory in RW metric with zero curvature? (so, definition of one-particle states...)

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want to know here - why do you think the denominator is dangerous in this case of "infinitely large VEV", but are apparently totally fine with this in the case of a finite VEV?

Comment: The questions are actually three (as written in the OP). 1) What is a physical meaning of a potential like Eq.(2) which blows up for very small values of the field $\phi$? 2) Is this kind of potential completely fine? 3) Why do physicists (say, phenomenologists) usually work with interactions with positive power of fields?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Let me add another interesting question.Take the limit of flat space time. Is this lagrangian renormalizable?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Let me add another question yet. How do you quantize this theory?

Comment: This is getting pretty broad - a question should focus on one question and one question only. "Why do physicists usually use potentials with positive power?" is a completely distinct question from "How do I quantize this specific theory?" which is in turn distinct from "What is the physical meaning of this potential?". Please ask them separately

Comment: I don't know anything about quintessence, but couldn't you just do a field redefinition $\varphi = 1 / \phi$? Then $\varphi$ has the standard power potential with a slightly non-standard kinetic term.

Comment: @knzhou Yes, you can do that. Also, you can perform a Weyl transformation of the metric to canonically normalize the kinetic term. However, this would change the theory. So, at most you can change variable as you suggested and work with a non-standard kinetic term. Then, how you would write the propagator of this scalar field?

Comment: *Is this lagrangian renormalizable?* *How do you quantize this theory?* Generally there is no need to even attempt to quantize the fields in such cosmological models. The handwavy explanation around such models is that these kind of potentials should arise as low energy effective action of some fundamental quantum theory (not necessarily QFT). So one should consider only classical dynamics, no need to try and quantize this.

Comment: @knzhou probably because that redefinition would mess up the kinetic term

Comment: @A.V.S. Thank you. Your comment makes sense (in some particular approximation) but it is completely unjustified.  Effective field theories can be quantum theories as well. I don't understand why "one should consider only classical dynamics"

Comment: @newUser: Sorry, I was imprecise. One should not try to quantize this model not because it is an effective field theory but rather because it is a toy model of how an effective field theory might behave. It illustrates some features within its domain, namely classical dynamics of cosmological solutions, but pushing this model into another context (such as local QFT) would be premature. In particular, our (in)ability to consistently quantize the model should not weigh in too heavily relatively to how well its classical cosmological dynamics matches observations.